# How to grab output from execlp command that imitates pipe?

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, popen

I have a C program that should emulate the same thing as calling:

```
popen("ls | grep som")
```

Right now I have two processes that each execute one part of this command and the firsts' output is the second ones' input. When I execute the program I see the correct line being prompted in the terminal but I can't seem to save the output to a string. I always end up with the first thing ls command prints out.

Example:
if ls prints out:
one
two
three

the string is always equal to "one".

This is what the code looks like:

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
pid_t pid1, pid2;
FILE *f;

int pid1 = fork();
if (pid1 == 0) {
dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
close(fd[1]);
close(fd[0]);
execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
}

int pid2 = fork();
if (pid2 == 0) {
dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd[1]);
close(fd[0]);
execlp("grep", "grep", "som",NULL);
}

f = fdopen(fd[0] ,"r");
// then I read the output with snprintf

//and once again I close fd's
close(fd[0]);
close(fd[1]);

waitpid(// first process)
waitpid(// second process)
```

Comment: You should be reading grep's stdout, it seems like you are reading ls's output and racing with grep. grep's stdout should be written to another pipe which you'll read from the main process

Comment: That seems correct. Will try, thank you very much :)

Comment: @thecohenoam what do you mean by racing with grep?

Comment: Both your process and `ls` will try reading from the same file descriptor. Only the first one that call's read will actually get some output. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another pipe for `grep`'s stdout and read from it from you main process.